# How to get a email notification once the Scheduling is failed in SAP CMC

Tags: crystal-reports, business-intelligence, business-objects

Could someone please help me with how will I get the email notification of the list of the reports once the report scheduling gets failed in **SAP CMC** (Central Management Console)?
Either it will be in single mail with the list of all the reports or different mails for each failure

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can schedule reports from the BI Launchpad or the CMC, the only way I know to do this is when scheduling through the CMC.

In the **Notification** section check the "A job failed to run." checkbox and enter your details. The placeholders presented as options in the **Destinations** section (e.g. Title, ID, Owner, etc.) are available here too, but you have to type the placeholder variable name (e.g. %SI_NAME%, %SI_ID%, %SI_OWNER%, etc.). Note that the variables are not merely "%SI_" plus the placeholder name plus "%"; "DateTime" is "%SI_STARTTIME%".

[image]

I would recommend emailing a group or shared mailbox so you do not have a bunch schedules to update if there are staffing changes.

Comment: Is there any way to get all the list of all the failed reports in Email?

Comment: You could use the Auditing universe that is discussed [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/07/15/unlock-the-auditing-database-with-a-new-universe-and-web-intelligence-documents-for-bi41/) and then create a report of all failures in the last day and email it. I have not done this myself so I cannot help you any more than directing you to that blog post.